# How do I write an instance method named product for this? ( comments have instructions )

Tags: java, methods, instance

```
// An instance method named product, which
// multiplies the values between min and max and
// returns the result.  For example, if min = 6
// and max = 9, then this should return 3024
// (6 * 7 * 8 * 9).  If min is greater than
// max, then this should return 1.  

public int product() {
      int runningTotal = 1;

      for(int i = min; i < max + 1; i++) {
        runningTotal += i;
      }

      return runningTotal;
    }
```

Comment: You have the right idea here. However, you are adding instead of multiplying like the instructions say. You need to learn how to debug code to find small mistakes like this. We all make these mistakes and have to track them down. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to start learning how to debug.

Comment: Have a look at [doc comments](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide).

Comment: `runningTotal *= i` is what you want. It won't work if the result is bigger than `2^64` (about 18trillion).